# User can't scroll much more because of list view

Tags: flutter, scrollview

I am making a flutter app and I have the next issue. The user needs to add the hour of the time they are open/closed . But when I want to scroll much more I am not able because of the scroll view don't stay intact much more .I will post o video to underwent better - https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4UL6.jpg

```
 Text(
                        'End Time: ',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 16.0),
                      ),
                      DirectSelect(
                          itemExtent: 50.0,
                          selectedIndex: selectedIndex1,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.white30,
                          child: MySelectionItem(
                            isForList: false,
                            title: elements3[selectedIndex3],
                          ),
                          onSelectedItemChanged: (index) {
                            setState(() {
                              selectedIndex3 = index;
                            });
                          },
                          items: _buildItems3()),
                    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried changing the background colour. Make it opaque and try it once